# Windows 2008 server SMB security

Tags: security, server-message-block

My understanding is that if I use .net `System.IO` namespace to write files to a remote file share it eventually uses `kernel32.dll` and SMB protocol is used behind the scene.

Let's say both source and destination servers are Windows 2008R2, shall I concern if somebody could sniff the content to write over network?

In general sense we all understand if http protocol is used the traffic is not secured, https has secured channel. Does SMB have the same concept?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Transit encryption for SMB was introduced in version 3.0](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn551363(v=ws.11).aspx), which is what Server 2012/Windows 8 come with.  (And SMB 3.0 requires Server 2012/Windows 8).

So an SMB transfer between Server 2008 R2 servers would not be encrypted, and could be sniffed, yes.  (As would an SMB 3.0 connection, by default - it's something you have to enable.)